# What can we say about eigenvalues of $A$ when $\dim\operatorname{Null}(A)=2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Consider dynamical system $\dot{x} = Ax$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

What can we say about eigenvalues of $A$ when $\dim\operatorname{Null}(A)=2$?
Can we say that $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity two?

Comment: With *geometric* multiplicity $2$. The algebraic multiplicity can be greater.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because the nullspace of $A$ has two linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2 \ne 0$ so that $Av_1 = Av_2 = 0 = 0v_1 = 0v_2$.  Therefore, $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity two, and algebraic multiplicity $\ge 2$.

Comment: How about $A^2$, can we say something about generalized eigenvector of $A$ for $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue.  Please start a new question for that.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for comments and reminding me the possibility that algebraic multiplicity greater than geometric multiplicity.  Corrected this.